# How to see which tests were run during Django's manage.py test command

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-unittest

After tests execution is finished using Django's `manage.py test` command only number of passed tests is printed to the console.

```
(virtualenv) G:\Project\>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
True
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.017s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Is there any way to see:

1. which tests were actually executed
2. from what module
3. in what order

I haven't found any solution in the doc.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can pass `-v 2` to the `test` command:

```
python manage.py test -v 2
```

After running this command you'll get something like this (I'm using django 2, feel free to ignore migrations/database stuff):

```
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('file:memorydb_default?mode=memory&cache=shared')...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
   Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  ...
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
test_equal_hard (polls.tests.TestHard) ... ok      <--------+
test_equal_simple (polls.tests.TestSimple) ... ok  <--------+
                                                            |
                                                            |
           That's your tests!  >----------------------------+
```

By the way, `v` stands for verbosity (You can also use `--verbosity=2`):

```
python manage.py test --verbosity=2
```

Here's the excerpt from the `python manage.py test --help`:

> -v {0,1,2,3}, --verbosity {0,1,2,3}
>
> Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
>                    2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output

Comment: I tried all verbosity levels but cannot find one which shows the unit tests without the migrations/database output. Is this really not possible without 3rd party libraries?

Comment: For hiding migration logs you could do something like `python manage.py test -v 2 | grep test*`

Answer (score 25):

Nigel's answer is great and definitely the lowest barrier to entry option. However, you *can* get even better feedback with [`django_nose`](https://pypi.org/project/django-nose/) (and it's not *that* difficult to setup ;).

The below is from: [BDD with Python](http://hentzia.com/blog/bdd-with-python.html)

**First: install some requirements:**

```
pip install nose pinocchio django_nose
```

**Then add the following to `settings.py`**

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-spec', '--spec-color']
```

**Then run your tests as per normal:**

```
python manage.py test
```

Output should look something like this:

[image]

**Note:** The comments under your tests can be used to give even better output than just the name.

e.g.:

```
def test_something(self):
    """Something should happen"""
    ...
```

Will output "Something should happen" when running the test.

**For extra points: You can also generate / output your code coverage:**

```
pip install coverage
```

Add the following to your NOSE_ARGS in settings.py: `'--with-coverage', '--cover-html', '--cover-package=.', '--cover-html-dir=reports/cover'`

e.g.:

```
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-spec', '--spec-color', 
         '--with-coverage', '--cover-html', 
         '--cover-package=.', '--cover-html-dir=reports/cover']
```

Then you'll get a nice code-coverage summary when you run `python manage.py test` as well as a neat html report in `reports/cover`

Comment: Hi @toast38coza. That's pretty neat. I'm new to Python and it's nice to see well formatted test output. I was looking for documentation for NOSE_ARGS, but none of what I found shows --With-spec and similar. Could you point me to that please? I'm basically trying to prevent nose from repeating "Similar to TransactionTestCase, but use `transaction.atomic()` to achieve
test isolation.........nTestCase might be necessary (e.g. testing some transactional
behavior)."

Comment: @MacarioTala the --with-spec argument comes from the `pinocchio` plugin (you can pip install that). See where it says: "first install some requirements" above.

Comment: Yea. I've got that installed. Let me try to find documentation on pinocchio then. Thanks!

Comment: In the interest of sharing, I swapped out pinocchio as it was a little TOO verbose, and instead of forking it, I found this: http://gfxmonk.net/dist/0install/rednose.xml , you might like it too.